# From float to mpz_t

Tags: c, gmp

I am using GMP in C. Is it possible to set a mpz_t to the value of a float?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a function `mpz_set_d` that you can use for this purpose:

```
void mpz_set_d (mpz_t rop, double op);
```

The float will be upgraded to a double by C itself and then GMP will turn that into an `mpz_t` type for you.

But you should be aware that `mpz_t` is an *integer* type, so you may lose precision. If you're just using the floats to hold integers larger than your `long` type, that should be fine.

If you want to handle *actual* floating point values, you should probably be using `mpf_t`.

---

To expand, here's some sample code and output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <values.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main (void) {
    float f = MAXFLOAT;

    mpz_t num;
    mpz_init_set_d (num, f);

    printf ("Max float: %f\n", f);
    printf ("As mpz_t : ");
    mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, num);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of the combined `mpz_init_set_d (num, f)` to simplify the code. This is equivalent to the two statements:

```
mpz_init (num);
mpz_set_d (num, f);
```

The program above outputs:

```
Max float: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
As mpz_t : 340282346638528859811704183484516925440
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I did want to truncate decimals. However now I realize I should be using doubles instead of floats.

Comment: conversely, would you happen to know how to convert an mpq_t to the best float approximation? i can write something for it but i was wondering if there is already something built in... couldn't find it

Comment: there is actually a function mpq_get_d which returns a double that approximates the mpq_t

Comment: @Joris, that would be better asked as a separate question since more people will see (and answer) it, and more people will be able to find it in future.